# Lucene: There are more terms than documents in field, but it's impossible to sort on tokenized fields

Tags: indexing, lucene, tokenize

I'm having an issue with one of my **Lucene** indexes. I'm trying to run a basic boolean search, and while the search works on other indexes, for my `products` index I'm getting the error: "There are more terms than documents in field 'Description', but it's impossible to sort on tokenized fields."

Here's the code with my query:

```
var luceneIndexDataContext = new BcsUsLuceneDataContext("rewardproducts", _dbName);
string fieldToQuery = "description";
bool sortDirection = query.sortDirection.ToLower().Equals("desc");

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(fieldToQuery, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query q = parser.Parse("\"" + query.keywords.ToLower() + "\"");

var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.Add(q, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

return luceneIndexDataContext.BooleanQuerySearch(booleanQuery, fieldToQuery, sortDirection)
    .Where(i => i.Fields["eligibleforpurchase"] == "1");
```

---

```
private List<SkinnyItem> BooleanQuerySearch(BooleanQuery query, string sortField, bool sortReverse)
{
    using (QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner(IndexName))
    {
        if (sortField != string.Empty)
        {
            return runner.RunQuery(query, false, sortField, sortReverse, 0, 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            return runner.RunQuery(query, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I think there must be a problem with my index, but I'm not sure what the issue is. The products index is working on other environments (i.e. QA environment) and when I copy the index from QA to local it works fine, but when I delete it and rebuild it, I get the error. I figure there's got to be a problem with some of the items in the index or something, but how do I find that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem is hiding inside error message:

Lucene couldn't sort on tokenized fields. According to official documentation:

> The fields used to determine sort order must be carefully chosen.
>   Documents must contain a single term in such a field, and the value of
>   the term should indicate the document's relative position in a given
>   sort order. The field must be indexed, but should not be tokenized,
>   and does not need to be stored (unless you happen to want it back with
>   the rest of your document data). In other words:
>
> document.add (new Field ("byNumber", Integer.toString(x),
>   Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

and since you violate the rules by using `StandardAnalyzer`, it's not sorting and it will never work for you. I have no idea, what you're doing on QA or other environments, but the issue should be the same (may be there is no soring on QA env?)

Some additional information on which fields you should select for sorting - https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html